# My tests isn't working with react-testing-library with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, babeljs, react-testing-library

I've got an issue with react-testing-library with my React project on TypeScript.

I've been searching on many websites an answer, checking tutorials but I'm really stuck and can't find the answer, changing some configurations on babel.config.js, tsconfig.json and jest.config.js, installing new packages (not sure if I had to install @types for testing-library for example) but I'm not expert with all of this and I'm lost.

I've tried an easy test and it says :

```
Unexpected token, expected "," (11:47)

       9 | describe('Test SectionTitle', () => {
      10 |   test('renders message', () => {
    > 11 |     const { getByText } = render(<SectionTitle tag="h1">Mon titre</SectionTitle>)
         |                                                ^
      12 | 
      13 |     expect(getByText('Mon titre')).toBeInTheDocument()
      14 |   })
```

The structure of my project is as belows :

```
    .
    ├── public                      # Where build files are (shoudn't be this way)
    ├── src                         # Source files (alternatively `lib` or `app`)
    │   ├── assets                  # All images
    │   ├── components              # All the components
    │   │   ├── component.spec.ts   # Test files 
    │   │   ├── component.styled.ts # Style of the component with styled-components 
    │   │   ├── component.tsx       # Component file
    │   │   └── index.ts            # Choose what to export
    │   ├── routes                  # All routes with react-router-dom
    │   ├── screens                 # All screens
    │   │   ├── screen.spec.ts      # Test files 
    │   │   ├── screen.styled.ts    # Style of the screen with styled-components 
    │   │   ├── screen.meta.tsx     # Meta tag of the screen with react-helmet 
    │   │   ├── screen.tsx          # Screen file
    │   │   └── index.ts            # Choose what to export
    │   ├── sitemap                 # Sitemap generator (issue about missing some parameters, changefreq, priority, lastmod etc.)[https://github.com/kuflash/react-router-sitemap/issues/39]
    │   ├── style                   # Helpers, utils, variables CSS, global style etc
    │   ├── index.tsx               # Index file
    │   ├── setupTests.ts           # Packages to be imported for tests
    └── README.md
    └── webpack.config.js           # Config of webpack
    └── babel.config.js             # Config of babel
    └── jest.config.js              # Config of jest
    └── tsconfig.json               # Config for TypeScript like imported paths with '@'
    └── custom.d.ts                 # Adding Custom Type Definitions
    └── .prettierrc                 # Rules for prettier
    └── .prettierignore             # Files to be ignored for prettier
    └── .gitignore                  # Files to be ignored for git
    └── package.json                # List of packages and commands to run with yarn
    └── yarn.lock                   # Packages in the node_modules folder
```

Here's my package.json dependencies and scripts :

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "framer-motion": "^1.11.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-cookie-consent": "^5.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-ga": "^3.0.0",
    "react-helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "prebuild": "yarn run sitemap",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "sitemap": "babel-node src/sitemap/sitemap-builder.js",
    "test": "jest -c jest.config.js --watch"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "./src/**/*.{ts,tsx}": [
      "prettier --write ."
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-typescript": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.0",
    "@testing-library/react": "^10.4.3",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^14.0.14",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.5",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/testing-library__jest-dom": "^5.9.1",
    "@types/testing-library__react": "^10.2.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "husky": "^4.2.5",
    "jest": "^26.1.0",
    "lint-staged": "^10.2.2",
    "prettier": "^2.0.5",
    "react-router-sitemap": "^1.2.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "ts-jest": "^26.1.1",
    "ts-loader": "^7.0.3",
    "tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "typescript": "~3.7.2",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  }
}
```

Here's my jest.config.js :

```
module.export = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
  roots: ['<rootDir>/src'],
  testMatch: ['<rootDir>/src/**/>(*.)spec.{ts, tsx}'], // finds test
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'tsx', 'json', 'node'],
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/public/'],
  setupFilesAfterEnv: '<rootDir>/src/setupTests.ts'
};
```

Here is my setupTests.ts :

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect'
import '@testing-library/react/cleanup-after-each'
```

This is my tsconfig.json :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "public",
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "paths": {
      "@assets/*": [
        "assets/*"
      ],
      "@components/*": [
        "components/*"
      ],
      "@routes/*": [
        "routes/*"
      ],
      "@screens/*": [
        "screens/*"
      ],
      "@style/*": [
        "style/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src",
    "custom.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

This is my babel.config.js :

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
  plugins: ["@babel/plugin-transform-typescript"]
};
```

This is my webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require("path");
const TsconfigPathsPlugin = require('tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js"],
    plugins: [new TsconfigPathsPlugin({ configFile: "./tsconfig.json" })]
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public"),
    compress: true,
    port: 3000,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  entry: path.resolve(__dirname, "src", "index.tsx"),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
    publicPath: '/'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: ["babel-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.ts(x?)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [{ loader: "ts-loader" }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [{ loader: "style-loader" }, { loader: "css-loader" }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/i,
        use: ["file-loader"]
      },
      {
        enforce: "pre",
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: "source-map-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

The component SectionTitle.tsx :

```
import React from 'react'
import SectionTitleWrapper from './SectionTitle.styled'

interface IProps {
  children: JSX.Element[] | JSX.Element | string
  tag: 'h1' | 'h2'
}

const SectionTitle = (props: IProps) => <SectionTitleWrapper as={props.tag}>{props.children}</SectionTitleWrapper>

export default SectionTitle
```

And the test SectionTitle.spec.tsx :

```
import React from 'react'
import { render, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react'
import SectionTitle from './SectionTitle'

afterEach(cleanup)

describe('Test SectionTitle', () => {
  test('renders message', () => {
    const { getByText } = render(<SectionTitle tag="h1">Mon titre</SectionTitle>)

    expect(getByText('Mon titre')).toBeInTheDocument()
  })
})
```

To summarize, the website is working, the build is working too but not the tests :/
Thanks in advance for helping me !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've forgotten an 's' in `module.exports` in my jest config.
I've added this in my jest config :

```
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@assets/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/assets/$1',
    '^@components/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/components/$1',
    '^@routes/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/routes/$1',
    '^@screens/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/screens/$1',
    '^@style/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/style/$1'
  }
```

And I've upgraded TypeScript to this version : `~3.8.0`

Answer (score 1):

Better to use as following:

```
interface IProps {
  children: React.ReactNode | React.ReactNode[];
  tag: 'h1' | 'h2';
}
```

Because:

```
type ReactNode = ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal | boolean | null | undefined;
```

**UPD:**
Or, maybe you have to pass children as a first parameter and a wrapper component in the render options, like this:

```
const { getByText } = render(<>Mon titre</>, {
  wrapper: SectionTitle as React.FunctionComponent,
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip ! But it doesn't resolve my error :/

Comment: Had to try, because at first look it was a type issue of `children` property. 
Have you tried to `render` without passing `children` ( in your case simple text ) ?

Comment: I've tried even to put a `<div />` but it didn't work, I've tried your update but it didn't work too :(

Comment: Then to get this resolved, we need to see a codesandbox example of your issue, please make it and post here, so we can check it out and help you asap.

Comment: I've created a sandbox but how can I use the console to launch yarn start ? https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-haslett-hl3p2?file=/src/myComponent.spec.tsx

Comment: I mean yarn test

Comment: @Bambou Here is a working example - https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-snow-os8l8?file=/src/myComponent.spec.tsx

Comment: Pay attention, that the issue was with `import "@testing-library/react/cleanup-after-each"`, take into the consideration that off. docs (https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#skipping-auto-cleanup) says: To make this even easier, you can also simply `import @testing-library/react/dont-cleanup-after-each` which will do the same thing. Just make sure you do this before importing `@testing-library/react`

Comment: The codesandbox is working well, I've tried but it didn't work in my repository :(

Comment: That means that you definitely have a configuration issues with React, mostly it takes more time then simply create a new app using create-react-app and simply eject all the configs.

Comment: How can I correct that ? I'm not an expert into configuring React, that's pretty weird since build and start the app works perfectly

Comment: I've already mentioned - if you are an expert in React configuration then simply create a new app using `create-react-app` and then run `npm run eject` ( this will remove `create-react-app` mentions and will `eject` all the configurations to the root folder of your project in a right place ), if you are not an expert - please create a new app using `create-react-app` and simply use it as is :)

Comment: Oh thanks, that means I can use create React app and have some configs like adding paths with "@assets" when importing files ? How can I do that? I didn't found any tutorial about that because create React app overwrite my tsconfig json and webpack

Comment: This should help - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/, as for overwriting - it does ignore them

Comment: But that doesn't help me to create path like 'tsconfig-paths-webpack-plugin' do inside my webpack.config.js

Comment: You don't have to do this at all. Use this docs as a guidance - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/, then, just add `tsconfig.json` to the root of your project and that's it